# How to Update Telegram on Android?

Tags: application-autoupdate, telegram

I have installed Telegram 2.6.1 on my Android Device.

I need to update it to the last version (Currently 2.7.0).

How do I update Telegram to last version?

Comment: Where did you download it from originally? Generally, the app store you got it from will provide the updates. If you installed it manually, you'll probably need to update it manually as well.

Comment: You can get the latest APK file from [APK Mirror](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/telegram-messenger-llp/) (AFAIK, it's secure, but always beware of 3rd-party website). Otherwise, you can compile it yourself from [its official source code](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Google Play Store, swipe right from the left edge.

Tap on my apps.

From there, navigate to Telegram. Click on Update. Accept permissions.

Comment: Is there any way except Google Play Store?

Comment: I'll upload the .apk to a file sharing site if that's okay with you.

Comment: No thanks. I want to update it inside program like it's desktop version

Comment: That is doubtful. It might or might not work.